# How can a directive wait for an element's dynamically interpolated attributes to be processed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive called "connection" that draws a connecting line between two other divs given the ids of the divs.  The ids are passed indirectly via some scope data.

My "connection" directive needs to get the bounding rectangle of the named DOM elements so it can draw a connecting line between them with the appropriate coordinates.

In my directive's link function though, calling `getElementById()` for these ids returns undefined.  This is because in the DOM, the ids of those elements are still in the form of `id="intf-{{intf.id}}`" when my connection directive's link function is run (i.e., they haven't been interpolated yet).

The divs in question were generated with ng-repeat and had their ids assigned dynamically.

### Main Question

How can I make my directive efficiently wait for the element ids to go through interpolation and then immediately notify my directive so that it can update its template and/or scope data?

Alternatively, can I force the interpolation to occur immediately so that `getElementById()` would work and then continue my link function?

### $observe?

I've seen that you can use `attrs.$observe()` to know when your own attr has updated, but I can't see how to do that with an arbitrary element's attrs.  In fact, I can't even get the element until its name is interpolated, since that is the only way I can identify it.

### Incomplete Solution

As an incomplete solution, the previous developer who worked on this code added something like this:

```
link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
   var deferUntilElementsExist = function( newVal, oldVal, cb ){
       var sourceElement = document.getElementById(scope.connection.source().id);
       var targetElement = document.getElementById(scope.connection.target().id);
      if( !sourceElement || !targetElement ) {
         $timeout( function(){ deferUntilElementsExist( newVal, oldVal, cb ); }, 0 );
         return;
      }

       updatePath();
       if (cb) {
           cb( newVal, oldVal );
       }
   };
```

This sort of works, but the lines appear very slowly, like 5 per second or so, even when there are hundreds of them, as if it's processing one line per update cycle or something like that.

Thanks.

Comment: Check for DOM lookups / manipulation inside of $watch expressions and then get rid of them. $watches should be light to keep the dirty cycle efficient. $timeout will wait until the render (interpolation) phase is complete before executing the code. If $timeout does not need to trigger $apply (which starts another dirty cycle), then pass 'false' as the third argument to $timeout. Finally, if you do call $apply, see if you can call $digest instead. $digest triggers a dirty check on the current scope (and not on all scopes like $apply does).

Comment: One last tip, if you are returning thousands of rows and rendering them in an ng-repeat, consider using limitTo filter to reduce the number of rows to a manageable number that a human can comprehend. Returning thousands of rows is just bad UI design, and limitTo will definitely speed things up. $timeout is the angular way of waiting until after render/interpolation. If its slow, i'm thinking its slow for other reasons

Comment: @pixelbits Your comment about passing false as the third parameter to $timeout() was quite helpful.  I added that, and instead of getting 5 lines drawn per second drawn, I got over 2000 lines drawn in about 3 seconds.  Using $timeout() for this seems like a hack to me, but it does work.  Regarding the UI design, it can show up to 1000 "rows", but I'm stuck with that design until we rework things in a couple of months.  Thanks!

Comment: Can create a plunkr for you example? It is because it give more courage to try and save time.

Comment: @hutingung Unfortunately not, since it's a closed-source project.  Seems though that the $timeout() method is the "right" way (or right enough) to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @pixelbits led me in the right direction.  Adding the third parameter to $timeout() set to false, which prevents an $apply() after each invocation, made the "Incomplete Solution" work much faster.

```
link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
   var deferUntilElementsExist = function( newVal, oldVal, cb ){
       var sourceElement = document.getElementById(scope.connection.source().id);
       var targetElement = document.getElementById(scope.connection.target().id);
      if( !sourceElement || !targetElement ) {
         $timeout( function(){ deferUntilElementsExist( newVal, oldVal, cb ); },
                   0, false );  // Added third parameter here set to false
         return;
      }

       updatePath();
       if (cb) {
           cb( newVal, oldVal );
       }
   };
```